# AJAX URL String adds spaces between the variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to use 'GET' with an ajax call but the url adds spaces bettwen the params

This is my function

```
    function getLocation(id,clientid){

        var formData ={
                'locationid'            :   id,
                'clientbrandid'         :   clientid
            }

        var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
                type : 'GET', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (GET for our form)
                url  : '/../admin/miscellaneous/components/global.cfc?wsdl&method=locationData', // the url where we want to GET
                data : JSON.stringify( formData ),
                contentType  : 'application/json',
                error  : function(data,status,error){
                        console.log(data+': '+status+': '+error);
                    },
                success :  function clientData(pair){
                        $.each(pair,function( intI, strWord ){
                    $("input[id=editlocationName]").val(strWord.locationname);
                    });
                    }   
            }).done(function(apiResponse) {
                    $('#response').append(apiResponse);
            });
}
```

This is working ok except the URL looks like this

```
http://somesite.com/admin/global.cfc?wsdl&method=locationData&{%22locationid%22:%222008013110482896439177%22,%22clientbrandid%22:%2235%22}
```

Instead of

```
http://somesite.com/admin/global.cfc?wsdl&method=locationData&locationid=2896439177&clientbrandid=35
```

Anyone seeing something wrong with my ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting your form data to JSON instead of URL Encoding it.

jQuery has built in routines for URL Encoding data which it will use if you pass it an object instead of a string.

Change to:

```
data        : formData,
```